# MySQL: How to skip where statement when the matched data does not exist

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, where-clause

For example, I execute this MySQL statement

```
SELECT table1.a, table2.b, table3.c FROM table1, table2, table3 
WHERE 
   a.id = b.id
   AND
   a.id = c.id
```

When there are some rows where `a.id = b.id` but no rows where `a.id = c.id` in this case,
no rows are shown in the result.

So, I want to make SQL to ignore `a.id = c.id` statement and show only rows that `a.id = b.id` is true.

Could you tell me how to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Can't you just remove `a.id= c.id` from your `where` clause altogether?

Comment: It sounds like you want to do a `LEFT JOIN ON a.id = c.id` instead of the implicit inner join you have now.

Comment: Have a look at [a visual explanation of SQL joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) and confirm for us that the left outer join is what you are hoping to achieve

Comment: I will say, on first read-through, the obvious answer is to remove the extra criterion from the `where`. However, I suspect that is not desirable for some reason. Can you please clarify the question and the desired result?

Comment: Thank you for your advises! I solve this problems using LEFT JOIN like Micheal Berkowski said. I am very happy to solve the problem. Thank all of you guys so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should *always* use explicit `join` syntax.  A simple rule:  *never* use commas in the `from` clause.

Your query, properly written, is:

```
SELECT table1.a, table2.b, table3.c
FROM table1 a join
     table2 b
     on a.id = b.id join
     table3 c
     on a.id = c.id;
```

I notice the table aliases you use (`a`', `b`, and `c`) are the same as the column names.  This is unusual, but allowed.

If you want to keep the records from `a`, then switch to `left join`:

```
SELECT table1.a, table2.b, table3.c
FROM table1 a left join
     table2 b
     on a.id = b.id left join
     table3 c
     on a.id = c.id;
```

This syntax is superior to the implicit `join` because it supports outer joins.  Most people also think it is also more readable and clearer.

Comment: Thank you for your advise! I solved this problems using LEFT JOIN.